# Custom field value not saving when it contains a URL?

Tags: php, custom-field, templates, meta-value

I implemented a custom field into one of my post formats called 'url'. When I enter a random string of characters into the field, it saves just fine and I display it in my template like this:

`<h2><a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, url, true); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>`

However, whenever I enter a URL into this field, i.e "http://wikipedia.org", the value doesn't save. What is going on here? Am I doing something wrong or do I have to treat URLs differently?

Comment: How you save post meta value save ... please show me the complete code

Comment: To save a custom field value as post meta you don't need to write any code, just use the [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin. This plugin will allow you to create custom fields for a certain post type or post format and save them as post meta values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some testing, I figured out the issue. With the Advanced Custom Fields plugin, you have to make sure your field name is unique in order for it to save properly. For some reason, I had another custom field name called 'URL' that was interfering with my 'url' custom field. After changing the name of my custom field, it all works perfectly.